# Insufficient Privileges while upgrading managed package

Tags: lightning, managed-package, integration

This issue may be requested by anyone but I couldn't find any better resolutions so far.
I have a managed package v1.87 which was installed few months back in different prods and test dev orgs. It's working fine and there are no issues. I have added a few changes and created v1.88 and tried to upgrade the package. Now I am unable to upgrade the package. I am getting below email.

> Insufficient Privileges: 
>   You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.

I do not understand what I am missing. I am upgrading the package using System Administrator profile. I checked all permissions needed to upgrade the package. I am trying to upgrade using installation URL.  Anyone please advice.

I tried to install this package in a new development org and failed with same ERROR/Problem mentioned above.

Comment: Are you logged into the same user that installed the original package?

Comment: @BrianMiller Yes. I have logged in as same user that installed original package. I am using same user to upgrade.

Comment: Any post install scripts that are touching / adjust custom metadata types? Spring '20 recently introduced a number of security changes and you may need to tweak permission sets in order to accommodate for these changes

Comment: Our application has post install script. but it has only log related logic. We are checking if this is a new installation or not and creating a LOG custom record. Nothing else. NO custom metadata types